# Inserting at the end of a LinkedList

Tags: java

```
public class LinkedList<T>
{
    private Node head;
    private int size;
    public LinkedList()
    {

    }
    public void addToHead(T value) // create new node, make new node point to head, and head point to new node
    {
        if (head == null)
        {
            head = new Node(value,null);
        }
        else
        {
            Node newNode = new Node(value,head);
            head = newNode;
        }
        size++;
    }
    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return head == null;
    }
    public int size()
    {
        return size;
    }
    public void removeHead()
    {
        head = head.next;
        size--;
    }
    public void addToTail(T value)
    {
        if (isEmpty())
        {
            System.out.println("You cannot addtoTail of a emptyList!");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(value);
            Node current = head;
            System.out.println("we are pointing to head: "+current);
            while (current.getNext() != null) // loop till the end of the list (find the last node)
            {
                System.out.println("we are now pointing to: "+current.getElement());
                current = current.getNext();
            } 

            System.out.println("We are at the last node:"+current); // its working
            System.out.println("it should point to null:"+current.getNext()); // its working
            current.setNext(new Node(value,null)); // make it point to our new node we want to insert
            System.out.println(current.getNext()); // it is pointing to the new node.. yet the node is not actually inserted (local variable problem? )
            size++;
        }

    }
    public String toString()
    {
        String output = "";
        if (!isEmpty())
        {
            Node current = head;
            output = "";
            while (current.getNext() != null)
            {
                output += current.toString()+ "->";
                current = current.getNext();
            }
        }
        return output;
    }
    protected class Node
    {
        private T element;
        private Node next;
        public Node()
        {
            this(null,null);
        }
        public Node(T value, Node n)
        {
             element = value;
             next = n;
        }
        public T getElement()
        {
            return element;
        }
        public Node getNext()
        {
            return next;
        }
        public void setElement(T newElement)
        {
            element = newElement;
        }
        public void setNext(Node newNext)
        {
            next = newNext;
        }
        public String toString()
        {
            return ""+element;
        }
    }
}
```

So I have written this linkedlist class, and every method works except addtoTail. For example say I create a instance of my linkedlist class, and call addToHead(5), then addtoTail(6) and use my toString method to print out the linkedlist, it only contains 5->. I debugged the addToTail and everything seems to be pointing to the correct locations, yet for some reason it does not add the new node (6) to the list. Hopefully I explained that clearly. I am probably missing something really simple (I even drew it on paper to visualize it but do not see the problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `addToTail` function is probably fine. I think the culprit is your `toString` function. In particular, in this snippet:

```
while (current.getNext() != null)
{
    output += current.toString()+ "->";
    current = current.getNext();
}
```

Your condition terminates the loop before reaching the end. What you actually want is:

```
while(current != null) {
    ....
}
```

Comment: ah wow, your correct, I completely missed that. Thank you Venkat for pointing out that simple mistake. Sometimes even looking at it for hours, I did not catch that.